# jquery isotope centered masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am having the toughest time with jquery isotope and centered masonry.  it always ends up doing a float:left.  i know on the older jquery masonry it was as simple as "isFitWidth: true" and magically it was centered.  what am i missing here folks?

thanks.

Comment: You have a stripped down fiddle to show? What have you tried? Did you follow the instructions here http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html and the github discussion http://jsfiddle.net/trewknowledge/4rEzD/1/

Comment: your jsfiddle helped very much - thanks. can this be accepted as an answer?

Comment: I've posted it as an answer. If it helped, you can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a stripped down fiddle to show? What have you tried? Did you follow the instructions here isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html and the github discussion jsfiddle.net/trewknowledge/4rEzD/1

Answer (score 4):

To get Isotope with Centered Masonry and Masonry Gutters try the instructions in this gist: https://gist.github.com/beausmith/4760823